# Selection sort with arrays of structs

Tags: c++

I am having problem with selection sort, I am trying to sort the students name alphabetically.I compile it and it shows me whole bunch of errors in VS.

I dont think it has do to do with my display all students function, I think it has more to do with SortByName and SortByScoreFunctions

any help is appreciated thank you!

here is the struct for my program.

```
struct StudentType
{
    string studentName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};


    void SortStudentsByName(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
    {
        int startScan, minIndex, FirstInAlphabet;
        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (NUM_STUDENTS-1); startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            FirstInAlphabet = student[0];
            for( int index = startScan+1; index < NUM_STUDENTS; index++)
            {
                if ( student[index] > FirstInAlphabet)
                {
                    FirstInAlphabet = student[index];
                    minIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }
    }



        void SortStudentsByScore(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
{
    int startScan,
        minIndex,
        lowest;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (NUM_STUDENTS-1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        lowest = student[0].testScore;
        for ( int index = startScan+1; index < NUM_STUDENTS; index++)
        {
            if( student[index].testScore < lowest)
            {
                lowest = student[index].testScore;
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        student[minIndex].testScore = student[startScan].testScore;
        student[startScan].testScore = lowest;
        cout <<"List of Students sorted by Score from Highest to Lowest" << endl;
        DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);
    }
}



void DisplayAllStudents(const StudentType student[], int numStudents)
{
    cout << endl;
    FormatNameScoreGrade(cout);
    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
            cout << setw(20) << student[i].studentName  << setw(10) << student[i].testScore << setw(10) << student[i].grade << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    EndOfList(cout);
}
```

when I compile here is the output I receive

these are my output results for the Sort by Name

```
Fibonacci, Leonardo        63         D
     Huffman, David        79         C
       Augusta, Ada        91         A
Goldbach, Christian        81         B
         Venn, John       100         A
     Church, Alonzo        72         C
     Fermat, Pierre        84         B
    Kruskal, Joseph        66         D
      Cantor, Georg        67         D
       Turing, Alan        85         B
     Chebysheva, PL       100         A
 DeMorgan, Augustus        79         C
  Karnaugh, Maurice        72         C
   Babbage, Charles        98         A
      Hooper, Grace        95         A
```

its  not working here

and this is the output for my sort by highest grade

```
Student Name          Test Score     Grade
------------------------------------------
                   -858993460         D
     Huffman, David-858993460         C
       Augusta, Ada-858993460         A
Goldbach, Christian-858993460         B
         Venn, John-858993460         A
     Church, Alonzo-858993460         C
     Fermat, Pierre-858993460         B
    Kruskal, Joseph-858993460         D
      Cantor, Georg-858993460         D
       Turing, Alan-858993460         B
     Chebysheva, PL-858993460         A
 DeMorgan, Augustus-858993460         C
  Karnaugh, Maurice-858993460         C
   Babbage, Charles-858993460         A
      Hooper, Grace-858993460         A
```

Comment: Sort the errors and show us the first errors.

Comment: Neither 'sort' appears to swap the entries at all.  The sort by score seems to move scores around, but not the names or the grades.

Comment: What, if anything, have you done to debug your suspect `SortStudentsByX` functions *besides* posting it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use compare from class std::string for this. Info about compare look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).
Another problem, you are not swaping students.
Please visit wiki for [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

This is my implementation for your problem. I haven't tested it hope this will works.

```
void SortStudentsByName(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < numStudents - 1; ++i)
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j = i + 1;j < numStudents; ++j)
        {
            if( student[i].studentName.compare(student[j].studentName) < 0 )
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if( min != i )
        {
            StudentType temp = student[i];
            student[i]       = student[min];
            student[min]     = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked perfectly, one question though. is that selection sort? because to me selection sort and bubble sort look very similar

Comment: Yes! This is selection sort. They have the same complexity O(n) but implementation is different. This algorithms are very good described on wikipedia. You can easily understand the difference just watching [selection.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Selection-Sort-Animation.gif) and [buble.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bubble-sort-example-300px.gif).

Comment: I just want to say thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help! no one wanted to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

change an inequality sign from the code you gave me and got this!

```
void SortStudentsByName(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
    {

            int startScan,
            minIndex;

        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents-1); startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            for ( int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++)
            {
                if( student[index].studentName < student[minIndex].studentName)
                    minIndex = index;
            }
            if(minIndex!=startScan)
            {
                StudentType temp = student[minIndex];
                student[minIndex] = student[startScan];
                student[startScan] = temp;
            }
        }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "List of Students sorted Alphabetically  "<< endl;
    DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);

    }



    void SortStudentsByScore(StudentType student[], int numStudents)
    {

        int startScan,
            minIndex;

        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (numStudents-1); startScan++)
        {
            minIndex = startScan;
            for ( int index = startScan; index < numStudents; index++)
            {
                if( student[index].testScore>student[minIndex].testScore)
                    minIndex = index;
            }
            if(minIndex!=startScan)
            {
                StudentType temp = student[minIndex];
                student[minIndex] = student[startScan];
                student[startScan] = temp;
            }
        }

        cout <<"List of Students sorted by Score from Highest to Lowest" << endl;
        DisplayAllStudents(student, numStudents);
    }
```